# Why don't community wiki questions display my gravatar?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, gravatar

I am curious as to why my gravatar is not displayed next to community wiki questions and answers. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: IIRC, there was a big discussion on here about modifying the format of what gets displayed to show ownership of a CW question/answer, but I can't seem to find it right now. Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's to indicate that the post is owned by the community, not by any one person.

Comment: Makes sense I guess because by nature, 'wiki' means community-edited or whatever.